# Installing .bin package on Squeeze thru GUI and without root

Tags: user-interface, installation, debian

I have a .bin package that was created using InstallAnywhere. That package has to be available on Debian Squeeze as a UI-based installer, rather than a command line install process with no root permission required.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that without root and through UI.

You need to do it through commandline, first login as root:

```
su
(type in your password)
chmod + /path/your/binfile.bin
./path/your/binfile.bin
```